# Jenkins git branch selection on scm triggered builds

Tags: git, jenkins

I’ve read the git plugin documentation as well as several questions here, but didn’t really get the basic idea of branch selection in git.

**Setup**

**Jenkins job**

Pipeline script with following stage

```
stage('Clone Repo') {
   steps {
      checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                branches: [[name: "**"]],                            
                extensions: [[$class: 'CleanCheckout']],
                userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'ssh://git@git.server/project/repo.git', credentialsId: 'secret']]
              ]);
      }
}
```

**Bitbucket server**

Webhook on each push pointing to:
`http://jenkins.url/git/notifyCommit?url=ssh://git@git.server/project/repo.git`

**Questions**

I’ve understood following by try and error:

- Bitbucket triggers on every push on every branch
- Jenkins checks every branch and tries to build a branch which has not been build so far
- Jenkins' branch might not be the same, especially on new created jobs
- After triggering the job manually, Jenkins has worked on every branch. Consequently every new push notification from bitbucket will lead to the build of the correct branch in jenkins

Is this correct? I wonder if this *implicit* branch definition might lead to unexpected behavior.

**Parameter**

Furthermore, I've changed the pipeline script to have a branch selection parameter fro manual builds:

```
    parameters {
        gitParameter(name: 'branch',
                        defaultValue: 'master',
                        type: 'PT_BRANCH',
                        selectedValue: 'DEFAULT',
                        quickFilterEnabled: true,
                        sortMode: 'ASCENDING_SMART',
                        branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)',
                        description: 'Branch to run the job')
    }
```

And the checkout stage:

```
stage('Clone Repo') {
   steps {
      checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                branches: [[name: "*/${branch}"]],                       
                extensions: [[$class: 'CleanCheckout']],
                userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'ssh://git@git.server/project/repo.git', credentialsId: 'secret']]
              ]);
      }
}
```

To run the job manually works fine. How can I trigger this job for the correct branch (e.g. overwriting the parameter) by means of the webhook?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your question, you want to accomplish a multibranch pipeline.

The link below is a tutorial of jenkins multibranch pipelines for beginners.

https://devopscube.com/jenkins-multibranch-pipeline-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks @JandaTheMan. I'll have a look into. Apart from getting the full working solution, I'd like to understand the behavior and the idea behind as asked in my question. Most interesting is the implicit (?) branch selection in jenkins which I don't really understand.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by implicit branch definition @amw ?

Comment: I mean that jenkins seems to take the latest commit on one branch which wasn't build so far without explicitly specifying it. This happens when on manual trigger as well as on trigger by means of the webhook.What exactly is the rue behind this logic?